# Blender Python add operator to menu with invoke_default

Tags: python, operators, blender

I have created a simple menu in python where i can add operators to it like that

```
layout.operator("wm.center_object")
layout.operator("wm.move_camera")
```

the problem is that I need an operator to be called with INVOKE_DEFAULT.

The following is the line to call it immediately:

```
bpy.ops.object.custom_draw('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

and that works, but i cant figure out how to add the operator to my menu with INVOKE_DEFAULT because the following is **not** working:

```
layout.operator("object.custom_draw('INVOKE_DEFAULT')")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use layout's `operator_context` field:

```
layout.operator_context = "INVOKE_DEFAULT";
layout.operator("object.custom_draw");
```